# How to set highlight color for selected text

Tags: css, python-3.x, gtk3

I have a python3 program containing this code snippet:

```
    dmsg.set_selectable(True)
    dmsg.set_name("sMsg")
    style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
    css = "#sMsg { background-color: #002348; color: white; padding: 4px 8px; }"
    style_provider.load_from_data(bytes(css.encode()))
    Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
        Gdk.Screen.get_default(),
        style_provider,
        Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

When text is selected, the selection is not visible. What has to be added to the "css" statement to set the highlight color and highlight-background color?

An internet search shows many results for HTML, but no examples fitting this situation. An actual example would be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

I may be mistaken, but you might need to add the css "selection" pseudo element.

So try something like this:

```
dmsg.set_selectable(True)
dmsg.set_name("sMsg")
style_provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
css = "#sMsg { background-color: #002348; color: white; padding: 4px 8px; } #sMsg::selection {color: red; background: yellow;}"
style_provider.load_from_data(bytes(css.encode()))
Gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(
    Gdk.Screen.get_default(),
    style_provider,
    Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
```

See [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/s/selection/) for more information

Comment: Your suggestion causes this error message: "GLib.Error: gtk-css-provider-error-quark: <data>:1:70Missing name of pseudo-class (1)". Can you fix it?

Comment: Maybe try assigning a class name to the pseudo selection element? Then in your HTML add the speciffied class to your element. See the edited solution for an example of how this could be done.

Comment: This is not HTML. It is Python3 Gtk3.

Comment: Edited the solution. Can you try now?

Comment: Sorry, same error. I am wondering if '::selection' is not a valid pseudo-element in Python3 Gtk3.